# AjaxFileUpload not working in iis 7.5 and Later

Tags: asp.net, ajax, file-upload

I am using AjaxFileUpload Control to upload multiple files at a time and for Drag & Drop functionality. Its not working in IIS7.5 and later versions .

Here is My Code:

.aspx Page :

```
             <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager2" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="15%" height="200px">
        </td>
        <td width="60%" height="200px">
            <asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete"
                Height="200px" />                
        </td>
        <td width="15%" height="200px">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</form>
```

.CS Code:

```
       protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string Path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UploadPath"].ToString();
            string filePath = Path + Convert.ToString(e.FileName);
            AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(filePath);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: it works fine for me in IIS 7.5, are you sure your function doesnt fail? put a breakpoint and go line by line, maybe your function fails to retrieve the UploadPath, or maybe your iis doesnt have write privileges into your UploadPath location and cannot save the file there, also maybe the file is too big, try a smaller one for testing

Comment: it works fine while debugging application . After Publish into loval system and Browse through IIS , Upload not working .

Comment: when you debug it runs from visual studio documents path, it has full access. when you publish it, it goes to a different folder. if by 'loval' you meant 'localhost', then it would normally go to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\YourWebsite`, give full access to IIS user to `c:\inetpub\wwwroot`.  IIS user would be either IUSR or IUSER or NETWORK_USER or ASP.NET or something like that, browse all users and find one of those (or more) and give them full access

Comment: if you don't mind can you please share your code

Comment: i just tested yours thats all. your code seems fine, i believe its a permissions issue here

Comment: I have given full Permissions even though is not working .I am Uploading 2kb file it is simply showing as error.

Comment: your catch clause is empty, put there `lblError.Text = ex.ToString();` and publish your website, check if anything is thrown in real time

Comment: Tried to display error in label that is also not working I though event not firing.By using simple asp fileupload its working fine

Comment: its showing Uploaded 100% and app_icon.png (image/png) - 2.47 kb (error)

Comment: there, ive posted an answer :)

Comment: no eventhough its not working

Answer (score 2):

We was having the same problem.

The control stop working when we update our sites from Framework v2 to v4.

We are using pool on "Classic" mode, that is the problem, if we **change the pool's mode to "Integrated", the problem disappears** and the control work just fine.

As we can't change the pool mode, we went to look for another solution... *and we found it!!!*

We add the option **preCondition="integratedMode"** to the handler's registration in Web.Config and *PROBLEM SOLVED!!* :)

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
        <add name="AjaxFileUploadHandler" verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: This should be on top!

Answer (score 1):

add the following lines to your web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="AjaxFileUploadHandler" verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You cant add a httpHandlers tag to system.web, at least Visual Studio tells me so.

Comment: maybe its .net framework issue? or you are referencing a missing dll? it works fine for me...